# How was the karma decided in our first birth?

Tags: krishna, karma

I meant the fruits we get in this birth are due to the actions of past births but what I don't understand is how our fruits(good and bad happening) were decided in the first birth because it was our first birth so we haven't done any action before that birth, so how were the fruits decided?

Comment: Any new creature is born with specific purpose for the first time. It continues to fulfill that task with purity until (due to maya in the world) it digresses. In that case the karma phal comes into picture and cycle continues.

Comment: There is no first birth. The jiva atma lived always like god.

Comment: This has been asked many times. Check https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32400/karma-for-the-very-first-birth

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Karma for the very first birth](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32400/karma-for-the-very-first-birth)

Comment: Please refrain from posting the same question, by using  Forums search facility to see ,if there are threads that already addresses your concern

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there the first birth of a jiva soul in the material world or not?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16683/is-there-the-first-birth-of-a-jiva-soul-in-the-material-world-or-not)